# Identify bike manufacturer using the number 1857 and is made in England

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have an Abeni badged track bike but the frame appears quite old. I am trying to ID the manufacturer.   I purchased it from an estate and the family said it had been in storage for about 20 years. That was a couple of years ago so I was thinking it was possibly from the 1980’s.

The number on the frame is 1857. Can anyone one enlighten me?

[image]

[image]

Update:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Missed one]

Comment: More pictures of the other frame lugs, dropouts, etc, would be helpful.

Comment: 1857 is likely the serial number, so don't fixate on that too much.   I'm guessing an 80's bike, looks to be built in Reynolds steel.  The paint looks far too modern, so I think its been repainted.   Can you ask where/whoever you got it from for more info ?

Comment: Any reason why this might be 80s in particular? Check out the headset: the integrated bearings didn't really exist before 2000s. Do you think someone worked with filler and paint to make normal headset look like integrated?

Comment: It seems you've created two accounts. There are [instructions on how to merge them](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in the help centre. Then you'll be able to edit your own posts without needing to wait for us to approve the change. (By the way, don't leave important information in the comment for the edit log -- nobody will ever read that. I edited your comment about why you think the bike is from the 1980s into the question.)

Comment: It's a decent quality frame, almost certainly steel.  The headset lugs are quite distinctive and might point toward a brand.  Most of the features suggest the 80s.  I note in particular the apparent oil port on the bottom bracket, a feature not seen in recent years.  @ojs - Looks like a bog-standard old-style headset to me, the only thing "odd" being that the fork crown seems a hair more "modern" than I'd expect.

Comment: (And the wheels are definitely old style.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks could you show me an example of that design instead of visible cup from 1900s? To me the complex lugs, curved stay bridges and cast fork crown look like artisanal retro high end bike from 2000s. The only feature on the frame that suggests older design is the oil port. The parts almost certainly from 80s, though.

Comment: Looks like Healing had both this headset style and similarly complex lugs.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for all the info you have found out for me. It has answered a lot of questions and is making a bit of sense when all put together. Fantastic work Guys. You should be detectives!!

Comment: I'll add that the crankset has likely been replaced.  There's a good chance the original was cottered.

Answer (score 8):

I might have traced back some info on it:

[This forum](http://www.bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34079&start=25) talks of Healing track bikes and one user mentions the underside of his BB is marked G.R. 23 and England, with serial number marked upside down on the seat clamp.

From there I [searched for images](https://www.google.com/search?q=healing%20track%20bike&client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=1AkKizPlMBrcfM%253A%252C7irHxZWoBXC4NM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kSsQ96nMq0V1tXh28PHv6t337HJSw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnnt_jhpvgAhXsUt8KHSV3CVEQ9QEwAHoECAAQBA#imgrc=_) of Healing track frames and stumbled into this picture, which would match the headtube style. The lugs are different, but hey, this one is from the 1940's...

[image]

So my guess is that it's a [Healing](http://www.aussievelos.net/healing-cycles/) track bike as it indicates

> Importing bicycle parts Healing was quickly gaining a reputation for his quality and service among the cycling community[...]

Which would fit with the BB shell marked as made in England. The decals are definitely just fakery after a repaint.

Comment: Yep, the lug styles of various Healing images you link to seem to vary quite a bit (though always ornate), but the seamless head tube (if you ignore the presence of a seam between tube and lug) appears to be something of a trademark.

Comment: It would also offer a logical explanation for Abeni decals. Both are Australian brands.

Answer (score 4):

John Abeni was an Australian frame builder in the 80's/90's.

He built frames for Europa cycles in Sydney as well as under his own name. There were lots of bikes sold with Abeni decals that came in from overseas but a real Abeni was pantographed as described in a previous post.

The lugs and dropouts on this frame look very much like they originate in the 1950's/60's. Even the rear track style dropouts in that shallow style that they have are much older than the Abeni era.

I couldn't say what its origins are but it is a nice frame that I would guess was re-painted by Abeni and sticker-ed up as such.

Comment: Interesting - OP is definitely posting from Australia at the time, which reinforces the location detail.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what it *is*, and I'm not an expert, but I'm pretty sure that's not an Abeni.

Googling around suggests that there are a lot of bikes out there where people have put Abeni stickers on a non-Abeni frame. Apparently, Abeni frames almost always have [the word "Abeni" stamped at the top of the seat stays](https://photobucket.com/gallery/user/whatsinaname1/media/cGF0aDpNb2JpbGUgVXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE1MTIwNV8xMjQzMDhfenBzdWJwbHNpdGMuanBn/?ref=) and Abeni [forks](https://photobucket.com/gallery/user/whatsinaname1/media/cGF0aDpNb2JpbGUgVXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE1MTIwNV8xMjQzMTdfenBzYXpocmJibGouanBn/?ref=) and [head tubes](https://photobucket.com/gallery/user/whatsinaname1/media/cGF0aDpNb2JpbGUgVXBsb2Fkcy8yMDE1MTIwNV8xMjQzMjdfenBzbW9jdjV4ZWYuanBn/?ref=) usually have a big ol' A on them. Furthermore, Ezio Abeni was an Italian who emigrated to Australia and started building bikes there: his bikes wouldn't be made in England.

Comment: My research came up with the same thing.  I thought maybe I might be able to identify it from the unusual position of the serial number, but have not been able to find anything that matches.